# Depth Estimation Using Inverse Depth?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have been trying to implement this paper, [Dense and Swift Mapping with Monocular Vision - Pedro Pinies, Lina Maria Paz, and Paul Newman](http://fsr.utias.utoronto.ca/submissions/FSR_2015_submission_53.pdf), where they start with an initial estimate for depth by creating a cost volume over an inverse depth range. I implemented this part using Sum of Absolute Differences as my photometric error measure. I compute the warp as

```
warp=K*LeftCameraPose*inv(RightCameraPose)*(inv(K)*inv_depth)
```

where `K` is the intrinsic Camera Matrix. I am not sure whether this is the right way to warp the images to match equation (1) in the paper. I expected the initial estimate to be the a noisier version of the ground truth but I don't get the expected result. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I have:

```
#Parameters from KITTI Calib file
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
K1 =np.array([[718.8560, 0.0, 607.1928],[0.0, 718.8560, 185.2157],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
K2 = np.array([[718.8560, 0.0, 607.1928],[0.0,718.8560,185.2157],[0.0,0.0,1.0]])

R=np.array([[1.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,1.0]])
T1 = np.array([45.48225,-11.30887,3.779761])
T2 = np.array([-337.2877,2.369057,4.915215])
Camera_Left_Pose= np.vstack([np.c_[R,T1],np.array([0,0,0,1])])
Camera_Right_Pose= np.vstack([np.c_[R,T2],np.array([0,0,0,1])])
Right_to_World=np.linalg.inv(Camera_Right_Pose)
K_inv=np.linalg.inv(K1)
K_norm=np.hstack((K1,np.array([[0],[0],[0]])))

#Inverse Depth values for search range
inv_d_rng=np.arange(0,0.001,0.00001)

def InitialMap(left,right,inv_depth_range):
    img_size = left.shape
    win_size =3
    Cost= np.zeros((np.size(left),np.size(inv_depth_range)))
    n=0
    for inv_depth in inv_depth_range:
        Pixel_to_World= np.vstack((K_inv,np.array([0,0,inv_depth])))
        perspectiveTransform=K_norm.dot(Camera_Left_Pose).dot(Right_to_World).dot(Pixel_to_World)
        Warp_I= cv2.warpPerspective(right,perspectiveTransform,(img_size[1],img_size[0]),cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,10000)
        returned_cost=CostFunc(left,Warp_I,win_size)
        Cost[:,n]=np.ravel(returned_cost)  
        n=n+1

    depthMap = inv_depth_range[np.nanargmin(Cost,axis=1)]
    depthMap=depthMap.reshape(img_size)
    return depthMap

def CostFunc(img1, img2, win_size):
    rows,cols=img1.shape
    pad_img2=cv2.copyMakeBorder(img2,win_size, win_size, win_size, win_size, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,0)
    cost_map=np.zeros(img1.shape)
    for i in range(2+win_size):
        for j in range(2+win_size):
            cost_map += np.abs(img1-pad_img2[i:i+rows,j:j+cols])
    return cost_map

img_l= cv2.imread('left.png')
img_r=cv2.imread('right.png')
I_gray_l = cv2.cvtColor(img_l, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
I_gray_r = cv2.cvtColor(img_r,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
IInit_map = InitialMap(I_gray_l,I_gray_r,inv_d_rng)
plt.imsave('Result.png',IInit_map,cmap='gray')
```

The left and right image pairs (taken from KITTI), as well as my result and the ground truth used are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzt_NZa6NrGEakcyYnMtNWtJM0U/view)